# Ole object - opening a Web page in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, navigateurl, createoleobject

I open the URL in this way:

```
ole_1.Object.navigate (ls_url)
```

Unfortunately not work for me navigate the mouse on the drop-down lists. How do I fix this?

---

I started example webbrowser8 from a web page
http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_webbrowser.html

The effect is different than expected. In the example I run a website https://www.persofoto.com/upload/index.php?mask=us. Use the mouse to drop-down list can not select the image size.

Comment: "not work" is quite vague. What is the result obtained vs. the expected behavior? What is the progid of the ole object? Could you post the code for the instantiation of the ole object (the line with the `ConnectToNewObject`)

Comment: 1. "does not work" it means that I can not choose values (by clicking the mouse) drop-down list. Only a tab on the keyboard.

2. What is PROGID? I do not see anywhere such a property in debug mode.

3. There is no line of `ConnectToNewObject`. The only code is: `ole_1.Object.navigate (ls_url)`. The OLE object is based on the window.

Comment: How do you populate the `ole_1` variable? Don't you have a `ConnectToObject` or `ConnectToNewObject` somewhere? e.g. `ole_1.ConnectToNewObject( "excel.application" )` to create an Excel instance, where `excel.application` is the program ID (progid).

Comment: If you run a website in an external application, eg. Internet Explorer are all working properly. Example:
`IE = CREATE OLEObject
IE.ConnectToNewObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")

s_ie = IE.Fullname ()

Run (s_ie + "" + s_url) `

The problem is that I am not satisfied with this solution. I want to open a Web page in object "Window" in PB.

Comment: Please complete an example....

Comment: Did you checked what Rolland Smith has posted? He has implemented a complete example where there is an MS based browser in a tab page of a window.

Comment: Hello, I do test and I failed to make it work. Any solution?. I found these web pages for your help if they are: [link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) [link](https://kevinragsdale.net/windows-10-and-the-web-browser-control/)

Comment: @EduardoG."failed" lacks some details on the problem :) What did you experienced? Error message?

Comment: @Seki When it used "Web Browser Control" the drop-down list html your options with the mouse can not be selected. [Add this in web control PB](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select)

Answer (score 0):

Do this before open window:

```
string ls_app
ls_app="Your application.exe"
// at design time ls_app="pb90.exe"

RegistrySet("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_USE_WINDOWEDSELECTCONTROL",  ls_app, RegULong!, 1)
RegistrySet("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_USE_WINDOWEDSELECTCONTROL",  ls_app, RegULong!, 1)
RegistrySet("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING",  ls_app, RegULong!, 1)
RegistrySet("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING",  ls_app, RegULong!, 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. Navigate the mouse on the drop-down lists are still not working. BTW: how to switch to navigate the website with the tab on the mouse?